# Alexa rank graph by country

Tags: ranking, alexa-skills-kit

As we know , Alexa shows graph for global progress of a website for example

http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/netshahr.com

shows the graph for world but not the country based .This would be useful for who target specific country and not the world. Please introduce a way to show graph based on country value .

Answer (score 0):

Found or better to say created because there is not same tool on the internet.

https://alexa.netshahr.com/dailyrank

You can track specific domain based on country . For example here is a sample for own domain
[netshahr.com alexa dailyrank](https://alexa.netshahr.com/dailyrank/netshahr.com/)